# How to intercept SSH stdin and stdout? (not the password)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ssh, pipe

I realize this question is asked frequently, mainly by people who want to intercept the password-asking phase of SSH. This is not what I want. I'm after the post-login text.

I want to write a wrapper for ssh, that acts as an intermediary between SSH and the terminal. I want this configuration:

`(typing on keyboard / stdin) ----> (wrapper) ----> (ssh client)`

and the same for output coming from ssh:

`(ssh client) -----> (wrapper) -----> stdout`

I seem to be able to attain the effect I want for stdout by doing a standard trick I found online (simplified code):

```
pipe(fd)
if (!fork()) {
  close(fd[READ_SIDE]);
  close(STDOUT_FILENO);  // close stdout ( fd #1 )
  dup(fd[WRITE_SIDE]);   // duplicate the writing side of my pipe ( to lowest # free pipe, 1 )
  close(STDERR_FILENO);
  dup(fd[WRITE_SIDE]);
  execv(argv[1], argv + 1); // run ssh
} else {
  close(fd[WRITE_SIDE]);
  output = fdopen(fd[READ_SIDE], "r");
  while ( (c = fgetc(output)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```

Like I said, I think this works. However, I can't seem to do the opposite. I can't close(STDIN_FILENO) and dup the readside of a pipe. It seems that SSH detects this and prevents it. I've read I can use the "-t -t" option to force SSH to ignore the non-stdin nature of its input; but when I try this it still doesn't work.

Any hints?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You should really be using `dup2` rather than `dup` to replace stdout/stdin etc.

Comment: `ssh` shouldn't care about the filetype of stdin, if you use a private key instead of a password.  Can you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) (instead of *execv*) to execute the ssh cmd and be able to read and write to the session.

Comment: Is the implementation of `popen` different in any significant way (i.e. other than `dup2` vs `dup`) from the code shown?

Answer (score 1):

A pipe will not work if you want to allow any interactive use of ssh with the interceptor in place. In this case, you need to create a pseudo-tty. Look up the `posix_openpt`, `ptsname`, and `grantpt` functions. There's also a nonstandard but much-more-intuitive function called `openpty`, and a wrapper for it called `forkpty`, which make what you're trying to do extremely easy.

Answer (score 1):

Python's [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) does all of this with SSH but it is in Python source code. However, for a C programmer, reading Python is a lot like reading pseudocode so go to the source and learn exactly what works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example that writes to ssh:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pid;
    int fds[2];

    if (pipe(fds))
        return -1;

    pid = fork();

    if (!pid)
    {
        close(fds[1]);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        char buf[256];
        int rc;

        close(fds[0]);
        while ((rc = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 256)) > 0)
        {
            write(fds[1], buf, rc);
        }
    }
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is probably wrong:

```
  execv(argv[1], argv + 1); // run ssh
```

<s>The array must be terminated by a NULL pointer, if you are using argv[] the parameter from `main()` I don't think there is any guarantee that this is the case.</s> Edit:  just checked the C99 standard and argv is NULL terminated.

`execv()` does not search the path for the file to execute, so if you are passing `ssh` as the parameter, it is equivalent to `./ssh` which is probably not what you want.  You could use `execvp()` but that is a security risk if a malicious program called `ssh` appears in $PATH before `/bin/ssh`.  Better to use `execv()` and force the correct path.